# How to get both the real and imaginary parts of a gabor kernel matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to apply the Gabor filter to an image of paper fibres. I was using the getGaborKernel function, but this returns only the real part of the kernel. I need both the complex and real parts to be returned, possibly as a pair of values for the whole kernel.

I found somewhat of a solution for this, which required changing the gabor.cpp file in opencv like:

```
double v = scale*std::exp(ex*xr*xr + ey*yr*yr)*cos(cscale*xr + psi);
```

and adding

```
double v2 = scale*std::exp(ex*xr*xr + ey*yr*yr)*sin(cscale*xr + psi);
```

However, this still generates 2 different kernels ( if we take v and v2). Hence I wanted to know if there was a way to combine these 2 and return a combined kernel.